# Using a function in Upstart configuration

Tags: bash, upstart

I am writing an upstart configuration file. Within it, I have a pre-start script, a script, and a pre-stop script stanza. Each of these had a large amount of identical code. Thus, I attempted to refactor this code into a few bash functions.  However, in so doing I discovered that "one does not simply write bash in an upstart configuration file". A bash `function` keyword is not allowed as it is interpreted as a stanza, and it isn't a valid upstart stanza.

```
# Some header stanzas that are boring
...
env ONE_OF_A_FEW_VARIABLES
...
function an_illegal_function () {...}

pre-start script
  function_call_A
  function_call_B
end script

script
  function_call_A
  function_call_C
  echo "I love pie."
end script

pre-stop script
  function_call_B
  function_call_C
end script
```

I would really like to avoid the kind of code duplication that will exist if I have to copy-paste the contents of each function into stanzas like those above. How can I get some bash commands DRY'd up into a common location and have each of my `*script` stanzas reference them?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in the configuration file itself. Instead, define the functions in a separate file, and source that file from each script.

Comment: Forgive me @chepner but could you either clarify what you mean or link to something that explains what you mean by "source"-ing that file?

Comment: `. /etc/my_app/my_library` or `source /etc/my_app/my_library`, where `/etc/my_app/my_library` is the file in which you define the common functions.

Comment: Will that allow me to mutate environment variables from within the source'd script?  (I only realize now that I ought to include that requirement in the question.)

Comment: Turns out upstart configuration files support almost no bash syntax, so including "functions" there is a moot point.  I'm not sure what to do with this question, given that information.